# Delete query inoracle db is fast but select query running too long

Tags: oracle, performance, select, sql-delete

I have below table with 160,000 rows. When I  use `SELECT ID FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT max(id) FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id);` query is running very long and not finishing (I wait for 1 Hr) but when I use `delete FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT max(id) FROM mytable GROUP BY user_id);` query is running in 0.5 seconds. Why??

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | MyTimestamp  |    Name        | user_id   ...    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 |  1657640396  |    John        | 123581         ...    
|   1 |  1657638832  |    Tom         | 168525         ...    
|   2 |  1657640265  |    Tom         | 168525         ...    
|   3 |  1657640292  |    John        | 123581         ...    
|   4 |  1657640005  |    Jack        | 896545         ...    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: For performance related questions it is required to have an execution plan. Please provide both for `select` and `delete`

Comment: Try `SELECT id FROM (SELECT id, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn FROM mytable) WHERE rn = 1` instead as it only queries the table once.

Comment: @MT0 wouldn't that be `WHERE rn != 1`?

Comment: @Bohemian If the OP wants the non-maximum values then, yes, you are correct.